# speeding up an sql query and fixing the join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query, which lists all accounts with matching facebook accounts- the issue is that sometimes there is more than one row in the facebook table that matches the join and then we have duplicate rows being repeated being returned even though ac.id AS id should be the unique primary key.

```
SELECT ac.id AS id
    , ac.first_name
    , ac.last_name
    , ac.email
    , ac.company_name
    , upd8r_facebook_accts.id AS fb
FROM upd8r_user_accts ac
LEFT OUTER JOIN upd8r_facebook_accts 
    ON ac.id = upd8r_facebook_accts.user_id
WHERE ac.`rfid` =  ''
AND ac.last_name !=  ''
AND ac.`owner_id` =  '121'
ORDER BY ac.`last_name` ASC
```

Two issues are duplicate rows being returned (i think its when there is more than one row in the facebook table matching the upd8r_user_accts.id. And the query takes 10 seconds to run... i have an index on upd8r_user_accts.id thinking this might help, but it hasn't

Comment: Please try GROUP BY ON upd8r_facebook_accts.user_id field

Comment: The index should be on the foreign key upd8r_user_accts.user_id . Also, your speed issues may be related to the fields rfid, owner_id and last_name, on which you even ORDER BY

Comment: can you show us the exection plan? (run the query with EXPLAIN infront)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tip:

- make index on columns which comes with `ON` or `WHERE`
- change `SELECT` by `SELECT STRAIGHT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Since upd8r_user_accts.id is the primary key - adding an index onto this column will not help matters and is superfluous.
The results of your query indicate some users have multiple facebook accounts.
You don't state the datatype if the id column(s) but you could try something like this..

```
SELECT ac.id AS id, ac.first_name, ac.last_name, ac.email, ac.company_name, upd8r_facebook_accts.id AS fb
FROM upd8r_user_accts ac
LEFT OUTER JOIN upd8r_facebook_accts ON ac.id = upd8r_facebook_accts.user_id
WHERE ac.`rfid` =  ''
AND ac.last_name !=  ''
AND ac.`owner_id` =  '121'
AND upd8r_facebook_accts.id = (SELECT MAX(ufa.id) FROM upd8r_facebook_accts ufa WHERE ufa.user_id = ac.id)
ORDER BY ac.`last_name` ASC
```

This would have the effect of displaying only one row per user but bear in mind the rows it removes might not be the ones you wanted to be removed from your results.
It also assumes you can do a MAX function on the Id column.